# Add cardholder name with Stripe custom checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe has recently launched Radar 2.0 to improve payment fraud detection.  One of the requirements for using Radar 2.0 is that you need to provide the cardholder name during the purchase.

I'm using the "custom" form of Stripe's `checkout.js` documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout).

The documentation does not tell you how to specify the cardholder name as part of the checkout process.  Has anyone figured this out?

I've copied relevant portions of my implementation below in case that is helpful.

If this can't be done, then I guess Stripe is insisting that people upgrade to Stripe Elements, but if that is that case it would be great for them to say so.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var stripe_btn = document.getElementById('stripe-btn');
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_live_...',
    token: function(token) {
      $("#stripe-token").val(token.id);
      $("#stripe-form").submit();
    }
  });
  stripe_btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options:
    handler.open({
      email: $('#stripe-btn').data('email')
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation:
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe Checkout does not support collecting only the cardholder's name today. There's also no way to pre-fill or pass the cardholder's name to Checkout if you already have it on your end.

The only solution in that case would be to collect the full billing address instead which would also collect the cardholder's name. This can be done by passing `billingAddress: true` to the `StripeCheckout.configure()` call.

Comment: Thanks for addressing all the issues so concisely.  Not an ideal situation, but I can deal with it.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill how you will deal with that because i have same scenario.. PLease let me know